# nginx redirect and basic auth woes

Tags: nginx, plack, psgi

I have a service (Plack) which listens on http://myhost.com:5000 
I want to password protect access to it with Basic Auth

When I set a server directive in the nginx conf file I get a conflict with Plack (can't bind to 0.0.0.0:5000 because it is use by Plack, and vice versa). So this brings me nowhere.

Then I enabled Basic Auth in the conf file with the location directive as :

```
server {
 location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
     auth_basic "Restricted";
     auth_basic_user_file /home/userx/.htpasswd;
     }  
 }
```

which when nginx "/" is hit it redirects it to port 5000 and asks for username/password. But my app relies on the url including the port (http://myhost.com:5000/) to find the resources and the port is stripped off from the request, so what it ends up is a http://myhost.com and I get a 404 on all resources/css/images/javascripts etc. Tried various directives like port_redirection etc.

I tried URL rewriting with :

```
location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/userx/.htpasswd;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

which gets the desired result (http://myhost.com:5000) and all resources are found but basic auth never kicks off so I never get a prompt asking for a username /password

As a final attempt it tried to protect the url with a direct

```
location http://localhost:5000 {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/userx/.htpasswd;
}
```

but that did not work either.

Can someone help?

Comment: Your first approach looks OK. What do you mean by "the port is stripped off from the request"? How do you try to get the port and how does it fail?

Comment: Also, do you use the `proxy_set_header Host` directive in your nginx config by chance?

Comment: @nwellnhof it chops **:5000** off http://myhost.com:5000/